# Vaciar lista y concatenar elementos

Tags: python, lista, pilas, spyder

Necesito un método `añadir`. Este método recibe en el parámetro `otro` un objeto de tipo `Queue` y debe concatenar todos los elementos de `otro` al final quitándoselos a `otro`. Es decir, que `otro` quedará vacío tras la operación (referencias `head` y `last` a valor `None` y `size` a 0).

Nota :

- En caso de que `self` y `otro` sean el mismo objeto, el método no debe hacer nada.
- Comprueba que la operación funciona en caso de que alguna de las dos colas (o ambas) esté(n) vacía(s).
- La operación deberá realizarse con un coste constante y sin invocar a los métodos `enqueue` o `dequeue` de ninguna de las colas.

´´´

```
Class Queue:

    def __init__(self):
        self._head = None
        self._last = None
        self._size = 0

    def enqueue(self,value):
        newnode = Node(value)
        if self._head is None:
            self._head = newnode
        else:
            self._last.next = newnode
        self._last = newnode
        self._size += 1

    def dequeue(self):
        if self.isEmpty():
            raise IndexError("dequeue from empty queue")
        returned = self._head.value
        self._head = self._head.next
        if self._head is None:
            self._last = None
        self._size -= 1
        return returned
```

Mi código

```
def añadir (self,other):
    otro = Queue()
    if self == otro : 
        pass 

    else: 
        other.head(None).last(0)
        return other
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Por partes:

- La linea `otro = Queue()` genera una nueva instancia de la clase Queue, ésto no es necesario, el método recibe como argumentos ambos colas, self (una referencia a la propia instancia cuyo método es llamado) y `other`.
- La línea `if self == otro`  es incorrecta. Que dos objetos sean iguales no significan que sean el mismo objeto. Debes usar el operador de identidad `is`, no el de igualdad `==`.
- Hacer other.head(None) es incorrecto, primero no existe el método head, es un atributo privado _head y por tanto no callable.

  En todo caso sería `other._head = None`, pero ésto no sirve de nada, aparte de para dejar la cola inservible al impedir el correcto funcionamiento de los dos métodos métodos públicos de la clase que dependen de que `_head` sea una referencia al primer nodo de la cola. Seguirá llena y `self` no tendrá sus items...

  Debes iterar y llamar al método `dequeue` de la instancia `other` para obtener sus items, al mismo tiempo usar el método `enqueue` de `self` para agregarselos. El método `dequeue` ya se encarga de eliminar los nodos y de asignar `None` a `_first` y `_last` cuando corresponda.

El método debería ser algo así:

```
def añadir (self, other):
    if self is other: 
        return
    while not other.isEmpty():
        self.enqueue(other.dequeue())
```

Si no podemos usar los métodos ya predefinidos y solo `self._head`, `self._last` y `self._size` podemos hacer algo como:

```
def añadir (self, other):
    if self is other: 
        return
    while (node:= other._head) is not None:
        other._head = other._head.next
        other._size -= 1
        if self._head is None:
            self._head = node
        else:
            self._last.next = node
        self._last = node
        self._size += 1
    other._last = None
```

Básicamente es condensar lo que ya hacen los métodos `enqueue` y `dequeue` , con una particularidad, no creamos nuevos nodos, se usan los mismos objetos  `Nodo` de la lista `other`.

Comment: En el método no puede invocar a ```enqueue``` ni ```dequeue```

Comment: Era un detalle importante que faltaba en la pregunta XD. He editado la respuesta, mira al final.

Comment: En ```other._size``` porque le restas 1?

Comment: Porque eliminamos un nodo de la lista (`other._head = other._head.next`), luego su tamaño se decrementa en uno.